# Nano, writing lines

Tags: nano

In Nano, when my text hits the end of the window, it starts a new line instead of continuing on the line I'm writing in. How can I change this?

Example:

```
This is a test, writing
next line
```

This is what I want:

```
This is a test, writing $next line
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `set nowrap` to your [`.nanorc`](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.1/nanorc.5.html).

Answer (score 1):

To **disable line-wrapping permanently** you can add `set nowrap` in your `~/.nanorc` file.

---

To **toggle** between line-wrap / no-wrap in a file you can use the shortcut `Alt`, then `$` (Shift + 4).

---

To **open** a file with line-wrapping disabled use `-w` or `--nowrap` (e.g. `nano -w filename`).